# Dont allow white space and special characters in the edit text

Tags: android

I am using the `android:digits` option in my xml file:

`android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM"`

When I input some characters and press the space-bar more than once from my device keyboard, then the space-bar works as a back-press event and is removed from the last character. But this should not work like this.

I don't want to allow white space and special characters in the edit text.

For Ex.
   I am input text and again press spacebar more than one times then start remove from last character of word.
For ex. I was input "Hello" and i was press spacebar more than one time then "o" is removed from "Hello" did same process again.
I don't know how is it..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely connected with soft keyboard "suggestion". You can add following property in XML.

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
```

This made EditText behaving as expected in my case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you found a bug. You can try out different combination of `inputType` values, but this can be device dependent. If that doesn't work you will most likely have to manually filter in Java.